# Filled values are not shown

Tags: r, missing-data

I am a new to R.
I had some values with NAs and i filled them like this
`katsastus_3_20211227_115940%>% fill(c("registration_year","reg"), .direction = "down")` 
when i run the code, at console i got what i desired, like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EkjL.png

and when im trying `view(katsastus_3_20211227_115940)`
i get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcBfK.png which is how the data was when i got them

Comment: `fill` donesn't change original value of `katsastus_3_20211227_115940`. Try to use `setnafill` instead. Otherwise, you need to reassign your result after `fill` to overwrite `katsastus_3_20211227_115940`.

Comment: i.e.  `katsastus_3_20211227_115940[, c("registration_year","reg")]  <- katsastus_3_20211227_115940%>% fill(c("registration_year","reg"), .direction = "down") ` assuming `katsastus_3_20211227_115940` is a data.frame.

Comment: it is data.frame. I tried what you suggested but i got this: Error: Can't recycle input of size 10 to size 2. @PeaceWang

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, e.g. adding the data.frame you want to change with `dput`.

Comment: @JKupzig `f <- structure(list(reg = c("2017", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    modela = c("Alfa Romeo - Models in total", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    registration_year = c("Years in total", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2002", NA, NA), 
    object_of_inspection = c("A", "B","C", "D", "E","F", "G","H", "I","A", "B","C")), 
row.names = c(NA,-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Answer (score 0):

you can reassign your data.frame (as @Peace Wang suggested in his/her first comment) using `fill`, e.g.:

```
f <- structure(list(reg = c("2017", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),      modela = c("Alfa Romeo - Models in total", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),      registration_year = c("Years in total", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2002", NA, NA),      object_of_inspection = c("A", "B","C", "D", "E","F", "G","H", "I","A", "B","C")),  row.names = c(NA,-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

f <- f%>% fill(c("registration_year","reg"), .direction = "down")
```

Comment: for some reason when i do  `f <- f%>% fill(c("registration_year","reg"), .direction = "down")` the data frame stays the same as it were but when i assign it to a new data frame like 
`y<- f>%fill(c("registration_year","reg"), .direction = "down")` i get the desired result